# How can I stop Chef from deploying code with failing tests?

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-deployment

I've been ramping up on Chef over the last week and preparing (emotionally and operationally) to cease our use of Capistrano. (We're hosting a Rails app.)

We follow the GitHub flow, meaning we just have master and a panoply of feature branches. Right now we use Jenkins for continuous integration and continuous deployment, and we use Capistrano to deploy `master` to our servers - but only after our unit, integration, and acceptance tests pass.

I'm using Chef's `deploy_revision` resource, and I'm thrilled at how well it's working. I'm eager to go from "push" to "pull". But I don't want to deploy code unless our tests have passed. I'm stuck on the choice between alternative approaches to achieving that effect:

1. Point Chef at a tag (e.g. `2.0`) and periodically updating that tag in our deployment recipes. (I don't like this because it isn't really continuous deployment. We are now back to hand-holding our code every time we want to release it.)
2. Point Chef at a branch, have Jenkins merge `master -> release` after the test suite passes.  (I don't like this because now my Jenkins server has read/write access to my repository.)
3. Don't configure Chef to run periodically, and instead have Jenkins run `chef-client` over SSH. (I don't like this because I was looking forward to a day when our Jenkins machine no longer had SSH access to our servers.)
4. Deploy the code, but revert the commit if a test fails afterwards. (Too error-prone, in my view.)

I do think I've done enough homework already. I've been following [Steve Jang's thorough write-up](http://tech.hulu.com/blog/2012/07/06/automating-system-provisioning-and-application-deployment-with-chef/), among others, and have spent hours of time on the [Chef docs](http://docs.opscode.com). But in all the excellent community tutorials on continuous deployment with Chef, I don't see any mention of this particular use case.

I could live with most of the options above, but I'd feel better if I knew it was a proven approach. I'm sure other organizations out there have solved this already. How did you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a small script that listens for a prod from Jenkins and runs chef for you - in other words, making a limited form of triggered access for Jenkins that doesn't require full SSH access.

Another option would be to have a separate clone of the repository that Jenkins merges `master` -> `release` into, that isn't your development repository. Then have Chef pull from there (or have Chef look up the revision there, and pull that revision from the original repository, which would give you slightly more confidence that no one had artificially messed with a commit in between).

Comment: Thanks, Amber, those are good suggestions. I may run with the latter option, so that I can still run `chef-client` regularly for infrastructure updates without necessarily updating our code. Have you put something like this into practice?

Comment: @AlexL. Similar. If you look in the Advanced configuration for the Git part of your build, there are options for using multiple repositories there. You can set up a separate repository URL to which to push successful builds.

Comment: Hey, I didn't even see that. For anyone else wandering across this answer, in a Jenkins job, the option is under SCM > Git > Advanced > Merge options > Merge before build. (Needs a few clicks to get it visible.) I'm going to get cracking on this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I have used is to guard actual code deploys in chef recipes behind an environmental variable (specifically, `ENV['deploy_build']`). Everything not related to actually deploying code is left outside these guards in recipes, and chef-client happily runs every half hour ensuring the base system is ready.

When a build and test run suceeds, the build system fires an ssh of the form:

`ssh deploy_system deploy_build=true chef-client`

which allows the recipe to deploy the latest build. This helps especially as our build system needs to deploy updates to servers in a specific order, so it can be orchestrated from a build system (jenkins)

Comment: So the deploy recipe would look at the value of `deploy_build`, if it's `true`, the recipe continues, and once it's done, it sets `deploy_build` to false so the next time automatic chef run doesn't trigger the deploy?